# Unity: Make ProBuilder Window Dockable?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I recently downloaded builderPro for Unity 2019.  When experimenting with builderPro, I clicked on a button on the top of the window and selected an option which would make the window floatable instead of dockable.  The problem is that now I can't go back to the dockable option since the button which I had previously pressed is no longer there. Does anyone know how to switch the window back to being dockable?

I have already tried removing the package and reimporting, but the windows are still floating.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the grey background part of the window:

[image: Right clicking the probuilder interface]

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I kept clicking on the light grey bar at the top of the window and couldn't get it to work but of course, it was a super easy fix that I just simply didn't think of.